# Balanced paranthesis in c++

Tags: c++

```
string isBalanced(string s) {
    int n=s.length();
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]!=s[n-1-i])
        {
            return "NO";
        }
    }
    return "YES";
}
```

I am not able to find the error in this code for **{([])}** and for every input it is printing **NO**.

Comment: opening and closing brackets are different characters!

Comment: Omg Thanks i didn't think of that.I look like an idiot now

Comment: As @CinCout mentioned, '{' and '}' for instance are not the same character. What you need is a condition like `if s[i] == '{' && s[n-1-i] != '}'`

Comment: Note that if you removed that mistake, your code would still not check for balance but for symmetry. For example, `()(())` is balanced but not symmetric, while `)(` is symmetric but not balanced.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a `{` to a `}` (and then you would compare a `(` to a `)` and so on), of course they're not equal.

Comment: Only the first comparison happens, after which the method returns!

Comment: Not downvoter, but there is a very good option for closing questions like this as off-topic.

Comment: @CinCout I didn't meant that the comparisons actually take place. I mean that's what his comparison logic would do. I'll update to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm will not work since you are matching the opening and closing brackets and both will be different.

Below is the program to check for balanced parentheses in an expression using stack.

```
bool ArePair(char opening,char closing)
{
    if(opening == '(' && closing == ')') return true;
    else if(opening == '{' && closing == '}') return true;
    else if(opening == '[' && closing == ']') return true;
    return false;
}

bool AreParanthesesBalanced(string exp)
{
    stack<char>  S;
    for(int i = 0;i < exp.length(); i++)
    {
        if(exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '[')
            S.push(exp[i]);
        else if(exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ']')
        {
            if(S.empty() || !ArePair(S.top(), exp[i]))
                return false;
            else
                S.pop();
        }
    }
    return S.empty() ? true:false;
}
```

Comment: There is a very good option for closing questions like this as off-topic.

Comment: OP didn't ask for a solution.

Comment: If you are going to force feed, at least do that properly. How is `ArePair()` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Your Algorithm will not work for all test cases for example {}()[].

My solution to the problem using stacks:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        stack<char> ans;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; i++){
            if(s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '['){
                ans.push(s[i]);
            }
            else if(!ans.empty() && s[i] == ')' && ans.top() == '('){
                ans.pop();
            }
            else if(!ans.empty() && s[i] == ']' && ans.top() == '['){
                ans.pop();
            }
            else if(!ans.empty() && s[i] == '}' && ans.top() == '{'){
                ans.pop();
            }
            else{
                ans.push(s[i]);
            }
        }

        if(ans.empty())
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        else
            cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
}
```